# Placement of portlets on a liferay page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using 1-2 Columns (70-30) layout for the page in liferay. The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to place them properly in 1-2 columns form even after dragging them properly on the page. I am making use of web content portlets. The portlet that should be placed on '30' side;its data appears the way I want on the RHS but the portlet window covers the entire screen. How should I place the portlets to get the exact 1-2 columns layout?

EDIT:

Is it possible to place a portlet over another portlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the portlets that you are trying to place are custom portlets, It may be worth checking if custom css width property forcing portlet to occupy more width than supposed.

You can't place one portlet over another portlet. But "Nested Portlet" can be used to include more than one portlet in their own layout.

As you don't have public URL, I can only suggest steps to debug your issue.

- Login to portal as Administrator.
- Create a new page.
- Apply liferay default classic theme to the page and apply 70-30 layout.
- Add one Web content display portlet instance in column 1 and another in column 2.
- Checkpoint: Enable Edit checkbox and see if the default portlet boundaries are occupying width they are supposed to take. If yes, then your liferay default working fine.
- Checkpoint: Select your web content article and see if width of display changes. If Yes, then the problem is with with your web content article.
- Checkpoint: Apply your theme and then see the issue. Then issue may be with your custom css files in _diff folder. 
  Use Firebug in Firefox or chrome dom viewer (F12 in chrome window) and observe which CSS style is causing the issue.

Comment: I am using web content display portlets. So how is it that I am getting issue? Can you guide me as to which CSS file I need to check. I am using a template which has header and footer and I am placing the portlets in between them

Comment: Is it possible to share URL ? Did you extend classic theme and created your own ?

Comment: Yes I have extended classic theme and put our own code in the diffs folder

Comment: As you don't have public URL, I can only suggest steps to debug your issue.

Comment: Yes Unfortunately I do not have public URL. I am working on localhost

Comment: Ok. I have edited my answer with steps to debug the issue. See if they are helpful.

Comment: I will try to implement and let you know :)